# How can I have a Tkinter program scan a text box for inputs in real time?

Tags: python, tkinter

Ultimately I want to make a small program with a text box where you have to type in the first 50 or so digits of Pi. What I want is for nothing to happen if the user types the correct characters, but I want something to flash red if they input the wrong character. For example, if the user types "3.1", nothing happens but the text showing up in the text box, but if they then type the wrong number, like "3.15", I want something to flash red.

```
from tkinter import *

def input(event):
    inp = (ent.get('1.0', END))
    if inp == '3':
        print(inp)
    else:
        print(('--') + (inp))

root = Tk()
root.title('pi, okay')
root.geometry('425x50')

ent = Text(root, width = 50, height = 1)
ent.bind('<KeyRelease>', input)
ent.pack()



mainloop()
```

What I think SHOULD happen with this is for the console to print "3" IF the user inputs a "3", and for the console to print "--(whatever else the user would have typed)" if it is not a 3. But what actually happens is that the program will print "--(input)" no matter what.

Comment: Getting the entire contents of a Text will always include a newline character at the end.  You can either strip that out of the string, or avoid getting it in the first place with `.get('1.0', 'end-1c')`.

Comment: Thank you SO much Jason, it is because of you that I have now enabled myself to forcefully memorize the first 50 digits of pi.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this if you need only one line of Input:

```
var = StringVar()
ent = Entry(root, width=50, textvariable=var)
def check_value(var, ent, *args):
    pi = "3.1415"
    if not pi.startswith(var.get()):
        print("wrong input")
        ent.config(fg="red")
    else:
        ent.config(fg="black")

var.trace('w', lambda *args: check_value(var, ent, *args))
ent.pack()
```

Here, `var.trace()` will call function `check_value` everytime when user types anything in Entry widget. You can add you logic there to verify the input value and change UI(or print logs) based on verification result.